# Getting NullPointerException On Location Android

Tags: android, location

This is how I am trying to get location in my android app. But Each time I am starting my App it is giving me NullPointerException  though i checked if the location is null. What is happening here? Please help me.

```
public Location getLocation () {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    //updates will be send according to these arguments
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
```

And this method running in a Service which I am calling by an intent.I am sending my Location to Server Using AsyncTask Like this:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service started");
        Log.i("asd", "This is sparta");



      new SendToServer().execute(Double.toString(getLocation().getLongitude()),Double.toString(getLocation().getLatitude());
return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
3-04 12:55:03.748    3235-3235/sourcemate.com.locationsender E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sourcemate.com.locationsender, PID: 3235
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service sourcemate.com.locationsender.LocationService@2f790e5a with Intent { cmp=sourcemate.com.locationsender/.LocationService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2914)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
            at sourcemate.com.locationsender.LocationService.onStartCommand(LocationService.java:75)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2897)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: what is your target sdk?

Comment: do you want to get the Lat and Long of the user?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath Yes

Comment: Are there two location?

Answer (score 0):

```
**I see that you want the Current Lat and Long of the User, the above method using GPS is not efficient.
Try this to Get the Lat and Long**

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();


        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
        .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    public class YourActivity extends AppCompact implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location =   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Service for that.
its functionality will be to get the lat and lng.

```
public class Location_Service extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private Handler handler = new Handler();


private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;



public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";

private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 2;
public MyLocationListener listener;
public Location previousBestLocation = null;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {


    return null;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000); // Update location every second
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, listener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
        //    Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
        if (isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
       //     Log.e("Lat/Long : ", "" + loc.getLatitude() + "/" + loc.getLongitude());
            //  Log.d("Provider : ", "" + loc.getProvider());

            Utils._LATITUDE = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
            Utils._LONGITUDE = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));


        }
    }


}

protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location,
                                   Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use
    // the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be
        // worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation
            .getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
    // accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
            && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks whether two providers are the same
 */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
   }
}
```

in your menifest file add below lines

```
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time having this problem, I finally realized that GPS wont work everywhere, in my case my parking lot and office building, not unless there is wifi or I enable and use the network location service.